# Migrating sitecore 7.1 search to sitecore 8.0

Tags: indexing, lucene, migration, sitecore, sitecore8

I am supposed to migrate a website from Sitecore 7.1 to 8.0

I am mainly concerned with Lucene Search and indexing part of search functionality which is to be migrated as well.

I just need a heads-up for errors and bugs for the same and a question (for which no answer was found on web) is that will the search functionality be severely affected by the migration? what care should be taken while migrating?

Any helpful and relevant links are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what comes into my mind, there were certain changes in search configuration

```
contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/analyzer
```

has moved to:

```
contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/analyzer
```

there were also changes in ContentSearch namespaces

Also check EncodedNameReplacements setting for media library as it may break some of your links.

If you are using modules - check modules compatibility table by this link  https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/541788 as some of them may not yet be available for 8.0. Sitecore.Kernel is now on .NET 4.5 so please keep .NET version updgrade in mind as well

I usually get two clean installations with following versions and check configuration changes in diff tool, where applicable, you may find this practice helpful as well.

Please go carefully through upgrade notes from Sitecore and consider if they have to be performed on your solution. Official upgrade notes to 8.0 can be found here https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/8_0/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_8_0.aspx (but you may need SDN account to access that)

Some other useful references:

https://theagilecoder.wordpress.com/2015/03/09/keystone-considerations-when-upgrading-to-sitecore-7-5-or-sitecore-8/

http://laubplusco.net/quick-tip-upgrading-sitecore-fast-easy/

http://www.velir.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/25/the-art-of-the-sitecore-upgrade/